# How to bring the closest value in a comparison in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have the below code:

```
Cars = ["Toyota Supra","Toyota","Nissan","Honda Civic","BMW","Opel Corsa","Toyota Trueno"]

for item in Cars:
    if "Toyota" in item:
        print(item)
```

The output for that code shows:

```
Toyota Supra
Toyota
Toyota Trueno
```

I would like to know if there is  way to return the more accurate value.

For example:

For Toyota 100% has to be the result

For Toyota Supra 50% has to be the result

For Toyota Trueno 50% has to be the result

Is there any library or way to see the percentage of equal value?

Comment: I think you need to better define what you mean by a "more accurate value".  Will you ever search for more than a single word? There are many ways I can think of to come up with a score for this sort of match.  One simple way, which happens to give you exactly the values you give in your example, would be `100 / len(item.split())`, but maybe that's more simplistic than what you want.

Comment: What you are looking for is called "fuzzy matching". One reference: https://towardsdatascience.com/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python-68f240d910fe

Comment: Software recommendation questions are **off-topic** here for the reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic).

Comment: The requirement is not properly explained. "For Toyota Supra 50% has to be the result" - **why**? I can think of several other possible results that make sense, and rules that would give those results. Aside from that, what are you going to *do with* the result? Clearly the existing `if` logic isn't going to make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you meant, or if this is the best way to do it, but I just calculated to how many percent the two strings match.

Code:

```
SEARCH_TERM = "Toyota"
CARS = ["Toyota Supra","Toyota","Nissan","Honda Civic","BMW","Opel Corsa","Toyota Trueno"]

for item in CARS:
    if SEARCH_TERM in item:
        not_matching_chars = len(item.replace(SEARCH_TERM, ""))
        all_chars = len(item)
        percent = 100 - ((not_matching_chars / all_chars) * 100)
        print(f"{item}: {percent}% matching")
```

Output:

```
Toyota Supra: 50.0% matching
Toyota: 100.0% matching
Toyota Trueno: 46.15384615384615% matching
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of comparing how similar two strings are. One such method is the Levenshtein distance, which measures how many single-character edits are needed to change one string into another. There is a Python library available for that: [python-Levenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/).

Another method is Ratcliff/Obershelp pattern recognition, which divides the number of matching characters by the total number of characters. An implemenation of that is included with Python:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

SequenceMatcher(None, "Toyota", "Toyota Supra").ratio()
# returns 0.6666...
```

Using the latter, you can do for example:

```py
sorted(Cars, key=lambda s: SequenceMatcher(None, s, "Toyota").ratio())
# last entry in list is the best match
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

SequenceMatcher(None, "Toyota", "Toyota Supra").ratio()
# returns 0.6666...
```